# Binary Search in C returns FALSE all the time

Tags: arrays, c, algorithm, binary-search, function-definition

So i wrote a binary Search Program in C based of the Wikipedia Pseudocode but it keeps returning false even when dealing with Array of just one Element. I cant figure out where it goes wrong. Any help is appreciated! Btw, this is a coding challenge so i did not write the Test Suit myself.

EDIT: The Function is being tested as followed:

```
int arr[] = {6};
size_t length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
TEST_ASSER((&arr[0] == binary_search(6, arr, length));


int *binary_search(int value, const int *arr, size_t length) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = length - 1;
    static int m;
    while(L <= R) {
        m = floor((L + R) / 2);
        if(arr[m] < value) {
            L = m + 1;
        } else if(arr[m] > value) {
            R = m - 1;
        } else { return (&m); }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

EDIT: So it worked with the following Code after i removed the const term from the original function. Thanks for all your guys help!

```
int *binary_search(int value, int *arr, size_t length) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = length - 1;
    static int m;
    while(L <= R) {
        m = (L + R) / 2; // no floor needed
        if(arr[m] < value) {
            L = m + 1;
        } else if(arr[m] > value) {
            R = m - 1;
        } else {
            return &arr[m];
        }
    }
    return 0; // not found
}
```

Comment: `return (&m)` doesn't really make sense. Why would you return a pointer to the index, instead of the index itself? Also, `floor((L + R) / 2)` doesn't make much sense either, as all of the involved values are integer values and the result will be an integer value truncated.

Comment: As for your problem, what is the data you attempt to search? How do you call your function? How do you check its result? Please try to create a [mre] to show us, preferably with a hard-coded array that you pass to your function.

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please provide a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) showing how you call your function and what data you feed in.

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question to add more details and information.

Comment: I think you should take this as the perfect time to learn how to *debug* your code. More specifically how to use a *debugger* to step through the code statement by statement while monitoring variables and their values.

Comment: Thank you, i tried debugging it just now in different Terminal and saw that the Execution went to the return (&m) statement but still returns 0. This is part of a coding challenge and I am using their Code Editor, but I just turned to my own.

Comment: Going back to my first comment, think about what you're actually return from the function. And then think about what you expect it to return, because that's not what the function returns.

Comment: The quick fix is `return &arr[m]`, but like said above, it is strange to return the address of an array element. Just return the index, and adapt the function return type accordingly, and the driver code.

Comment: Nope. You did not. Wikipedia says `return m;` while you did `return &m;` which is quite a different thing. Additionally your test assertion is incompatible with the code being tested - you return a pointer to a variable `m` with an index value, and the test expects a pointer to an array's item `a[0]`. This simply **can not work**.

Comment: The Coding Challenge prewrote the Function so it returns an int Pointer while Wikipedia did not

Comment: There is no need for `m` to be declared `static` in your edited version. Also, if you want to restore the `const`ness of the original version, you could change the return type of the function to `const int *`.

Answer (score 1):

The length of the array is declared as having the type `size_t`

```
int *binary_search(int value, const int *arr, size_t length) {
```

So within the function the variables `L`, `R` and `m` also should be declared as having the type `size_t`.

Also using the function floor

```
m = floor((L + R) / 2);
```

absolutely does not make a sense because the expression `(L + R) / 2` has the integer type `int`.

Declaring the variable `m` as static also does not make a great sense.

The function should return the position of the found element in the array or the size of the array if such an element is not found.

In this condition

```
TEST_ASSER((&arr[0] == binary_search(6, arr, length));
```

there are compared address of the first element of the array `arr` with the address of the static local variable `m`. It is evident that these objects occupy different extents of memory. So the condition will always evaluate to logical false.

The function can be declared an defined for example the following way as shown in the demonstrative program below.

```
#include <stdio.h>

size_t binary_search( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    size_t low = 0, high = n;
    
    while ( low < high )
    {
        size_t middle = low + ( high - low ) / 2;
        
        if ( value < a[middle] )
        {
            high = middle;
        }
        else if ( a[middle] < value )
        {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return middle;
        }
    }
    
    return n;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    int value = 6;
    
    size_t pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != N )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %zu\n", value, pos );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    value = 5;
    
    pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != N )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %zu\n", value, pos );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    value = 7;
    
    pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != N )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %zu\n", value, pos );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is

```
The value 6 is found at position 0
The value 5 is not found.
The value 7 is not found
```

Another approach is to define the function such a way that it will return a pointer to the found element in the array or `NULL` if such an element is not found.

Here is one more demonstrative program.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int * binary_search( const int a[], size_t n, int value )
{
    size_t low = 0, high = n;
    
    while ( low < high )
    {
        size_t middle = low + ( high - low ) / 2;
        
        if ( value < a[middle] )
        {
            high = middle;
        }
        else if ( a[middle] < value )
        {
            low = middle + 1;
        }
        else
        {
            return ( int * )( a + middle );
        }
    }
    
    return NULL;
}

int main(void) 
{
    int a[] = { 6 };
    const size_t N = sizeof( a ) / sizeof( *a );
    
    int value = 6;
    
    int *pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != NULL )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %tu\n", value, pos - a );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    value = 5;
    
    pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != NULL )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %tu\n", value, pos - a );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    value = 7;
    
    pos = binary_search( a, N, value );
    
    if ( pos != NULL )
    {
        printf( "The value %d is found at position %tu\n", value, pos - a );
    }
    else
    {
        printf( "The value %d is not found.\n", value );
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

The program output is the same as shown above.

```
The value 6 is found at position 0
The value 5 is not found.
The value 7 is not found.
```

Answer (score 0):

the logic of binary search should be like this

```
int *binary_search(int value, const int *arr, size_t length) {
        int L = 0;
        int R = length - 1;
        static int m;
        while(L <= R) {
          m = floor((L + R) / 2);
          if(arr[m]==value)
          {
          // element found
          }
           else if(arr[m] < value) {
                L = m + 1;
            } else if(arr[m] > value) {
                R = m - 1;
            } 
        }
        return 0;
    }
```

if while loop executed and not entered inside  `if(arr[m]==value)` means element not in the list

Comment: The Asker already had the logic to identify equality. Your code is not adding anything to that.

Answer (score 0):

Your `return` statement returns the address of a local variable: `&m`. This is definitely wrong, as this memory is no longer allocated after the function returns, and it certainly is not the address that is expected in the driver code you have.

The quick fix is `return &arr[m]`, but like said in comments, it is strange to return the address of an array element.

Just return the index, and adapt the function return type accordingly, and the driver code:

```
#include <stdio.h>


int binary_search(int value, const int *arr, size_t length) {
    int L = 0;
    int R = length - 1;
    static int m;
    while(L <= R) {
        m = (L + R) / 2; // no floor needed
        if(arr[m] < value) {
            L = m + 1;
        } else if(arr[m] > value) {
            R = m - 1;
        } else {
            return m;
        }
    }
    return -1; // not found
}

int main(void) {
    printf("Hello World\n");
    int arr[] = {6, 9, 13, 25};
    size_t length = sizeof(arr)/sizeof(*arr);
    if (1 == binary_search(6, arr, length)) {
        printf("ok!\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem seems to be that the Function returns an Integer Pointer. The compiler gives this Error: returning 'int' from a function with return type 'int *' makes pointer from integer without a cast...